# sudo service sshd restart failed on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, amazon-ec2

I have created AWS EC2 instance and deployed Asp.Net Core Web API application. It works when deploying into server. After an hour, I was not able to connect my server using PUTTY or WinSCP. When i am trying to connect it says "**Network error: Connection Refused**".

**My server details are**

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

After i researched from google, many suggested to check with AWS command session. If i given "**sudo service sshd restart**" it says "Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart sshd.service
Job for sshd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "**systemctl status sshd.service**" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

If i check with "**systemctl status shd.service**" then below message i got,

```
    sh-4.2$ systemctl status sshd.service
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-08-11 18:48:15 UTC; 18s ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
  Process: 4053 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4053 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

So, kindly help me in this regards.

Comment: maybe a permission error on amazon side / check your routeur & ports as first action

Comment: Don't know how to check?

Comment: You were directed to look at the output of journalctl what did that tell you?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got that error when there was an issue with the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. Specifically Subsystem was being called twice. If you made any file edits or changes before attempting to restart, that could be the problem. Check `journalctl -xe` for debugging.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind explaining a little further how you noticed the duplicate Subsystem call, and how to identify the faulty configuration in the `sshd_config` file (e.g. by giving - possibly anonymized - extracts of such a faulty file)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed something in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Try `journalctl -xe` and `journalctl -u sshd` to see if there's any error. Look in `/var/log/auth.log` and `/var/log/syslog` to see if there are any errors. It looks like configuration error or something close to it like lack of ability to bind itself to network address/port.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```

Comment: The question mentions that this was run (indirectly, through `service`).